# How to type node-postgres async query functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-await, typing, node-postgres

I am fairly new to TypeScript and started to convert my existing server from ES6 to TypeScript. I am a bit lost and trying to figure out how to declare types for async functions. Here's a stub from the ES6 code:

```js
// db.js
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: 'process.env.DB_CONNECTION',
});

export default {

  query(text, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const result = pool.query(text, params);
        return resolve(result);
      } catch (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  },
};

// controller for a table
const Table = {
  getOne: async (id) => {
    return await db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$1', [id]);
  },
}
```

This works fine and could be processed by consuming part in a try/catch block and it works whether the query returns a result or an error. Now how should I type these in typescript? I tried doing this:

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: 'process.env.DB_CONNECTION',
});

export default {

  query(text: string, params: any[]) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const result = pool.query(text, params);
        return resolve(result);
      } catch (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
    });
  },
};

// controller
import { QueryResult } from 'pg';

const Table = {
  getOne: async (id: string) => {
    return await db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$1', [id]) as QueryResult;
  },
}
```

Now, this compiles, but there are couple things I don't get. First, it is quite redundant to always cast these return types with 'as'. Shouldn't I be able to declare the return type somehow like this `getOne: async (id: string): Promise<QueryResult> => {...}`? Then, what would happen, if the promise rejected? That isn't a QueryResult type anymore afaik. I have tried to read the documentations about node-postgres and TypeScript function type declarations, but I am getting nowhere. How I should do these? Also probably I should start learning declaration files too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

async functions implicitly return promises

example:

```
// Declare async function
async function getRandomNumberAsync(max: number): Promise<number> {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

// Call it (errors are handled with a try/catch)
try {
  const result = await getRandomNumberAsync(100);
  console.log(result);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("something went wrong");
}
```

async/await is just syntax sugar (behind the scenes, async/await use Promises). This code is basically equivalent to the above code

```
function getRandomNumberAsync(max: number): Promise<number> {
  return Promise.resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max)));
}

getRandomNumberAsync(100).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(e => {
  console.error("something went wrong");
})
```

I can see that in your code, you're using `return await` which is redundant. There's even an [eslint rule](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/docs/rules/no-return-await.md) to prevent this

Your code should look something like this

```
const Table = {
  getOne: async (id: string): Promise<QueryResult> => {
    return db.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$1', [id]);
  },
}

// "getOne" should be called like this
try {
  const result = await Table.getOne("YOUR_ID");
  // handle result
} catch (e) {
  // handle error
}
```

unless you want to handle `query` errors inside `getOne`

It should look something like this

```
const Table = {
  getOne: async (id: string): Promise<QueryResult | string> => {
    try {
      return await db.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$1", [id]);
    } catch (e) {
      return "something went wrong";
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive answer. I'll digest it a bit and might accept it soon. Also about the redundant usage of await, I know it is redundant, but I have use it as a reminder that there's a promise returning to whoever calls that function. I don't know, if that would be problematic in some cases, but at least so far it has worked. I'll try to get rid of that habit though, as I think it might not be a good coding practice.

Comment: It seems to be an elegant solution to return the queries as promises. However, if I decided to resolve the promises inside the functions and return the resolved result, TS still requires me to declare the return type as Promise<...>. Why? Maybe I should write a whole new question about this.

Comment: @zaplec When you declare a function as async, the result is always wrapped in a Promise. Take a function like `async () => 1`... it's return type would be Promise<number>, because under the hood the "async" keyword will cause the return value to be wrapped in a promise automatically. It'd be equivalent to the non-async function `() => Promise.resolve(1)`